# Muting sound or changing lanuage shortcuts not working on lockscreen

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, lock-screen, input-language

I 've been using Ubuntu for some months now and I have noticed something that really bothers me.

When I am on the lock-screen and I want to mute music using the <kbd>fn+F11</kbd> this key combination won't work.However when I have unlocked my computer and press the same key combination the sound will mute.Same goes for changing my language using <kbd>superkey+space</kbd>

Any ideas if there is any workaround here?

I use Ubuntu budgie remix 17.04

Comment: I don't know about Budgie but all the others I've used let users change the keyboard language at the greeter but it shouldn't matter anyway because the only thing to input in a greeter is the password.

Comment: Just tested, mute also works in the greeter - Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity/LightDM). Perhaps Budgie's default greeter (don' t know which one) doesn't support shortcuts.